# Variables in LT Spice Value

Tags: ltspice, simulation, components, variable

Is it possible to add a variable into the value of a component in LT spice? I'd like to simulate a resistor divider to look at current consumption but keep the ratio of the resistances the same.

I tried setting R1 to {X} and R2 to {X*1.5} but couldn't get it to work correctly. Haven't found the solution on Google and haven't been able to successfully run it. Maybe I need to define X somewhere.

Comment: Are you saying that a google search of "ltspice parameter" returned **nothing**? If you tried **something** then show us what you tried...if it didn't work for you then we won't waste time suggesting the same approach again.

Comment: I had already tried what I mentioned, should've said that and updated post to show that.

Comment: @Pete Yes, you need to define **X**!! Use the .param card. Look it up in the help. While you are at it, look up the .func card, as well. And type in 'user-defined functions' into the help, as well. It's a short summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1 won't accept 1.5*Rx directly but it can be assigned to a variable. Rx can be used in the .step param statement.

[image]

Comment: Why did you say "*R1 won't accept 1.5*Rx directly*"? [It sure can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsTnI.png). The curly braces are needed to enclose the value and tell SPICE to perform an evaluation, since a resistor (not a behavioural one, like your `R1`) can only accept numeric literals as values.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I typed 1.5* Rx in the box directly and it didn't accept it (obviously) so I used this method which is redundant.